# Only Search for Text Within XAML Files using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio

Many times I find that I want to search my entire Visual Studio project for a text string, but I only want to search the XAML files in the project and not the code-behind (.cs) files.

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this in Visual Studio or if there is an add-in I can download to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried using the `Find In Files` (`Edit->Find and Replace->Find in Files` (Ctrl+Shift+F)), and then specify a `File Type` in the `Find` options.  Add `*.xaml` to do just XAML files.

Comment: Yep, that's what I needed. Can't believe I didn't know about that considering I've been using Visual Studio for years. Thanks.